# Running shell script from php file

Tags: bash, shell, variables, exec, shell-exec

Basically I'm trying to achieve the following:
1.Create a php form to get the new databse name and instance name.
Here's my a.txt file:

```
<form class = "myform" action="b.php" method="post">
<h1> Create new instance: </h1>
<br>
Term1 name: <input type = "textbox" id="dbname" name="dbname"></input>
Term2 name: <input type = "textbox" id="instancename" name="instancename"></input>
<button style "color:red;" type="submit" >create</button>
</form>
```

2. Pass these parameters to Shell script. Here's my b.php file:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST["dbname"];
$b = $_POST["instancename"];
exec("./b.sh $a $b");
```

3. My shellscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -p'password' currentdb > /home/admin/mydb.sql
echo "create database" $1 | mysql -u root -p'password'
mysql -u root -p'password' $1 < /home/admin/mydb.sql

mkdir /var/www/instance/$2
chmod -R 777 /var/www/instance/$2

cp -r /var/www/instance/current/* /var/www/instance/$2/
cd /var/www/instance/$2/
sed -i 's/currentdb/$1/g' configuration.php
```

I'm able to get the parameters to my shellscript, but my problem is, my shellscript does not run any of thses lines when I click submit on my form. But If I directly run the shellscript using /.sh by replacing all variables with manually entered values it works perfectly. I suspect I'm not handling the variables correctly. Please help.

Comment: Put the full path to the b.sh script in you php exec syntax and ensure that the user your web daemon is running under has permission to execute the script.

Comment: ful path in the commands on the shell script as well (/usr/bin/dump etc)

Comment: As I said, I'm getting the parameters to .sh correctly. The problem is (I think)  in the syntax of using these variables In my shell script.